# How to store data to variable from SQL query in ASP net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So here is my code. What I'm trying to do store double rate_num value to number variable. But it is still getting an error.

```
String conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string query = "select " + rate_from + " from Exchange_rate where ERates_Status = 'Active'";
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(conn);
    sqlcon.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    double number = "";

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        double rate_num = reader.GetDouble(0);

        number = rate_num
    }

    number;

    sqlcon.Close();
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: there is red underline in the number variable, below the bracket

Comment: What is the error message? When you hover your mouse over the red line, what does it say?

Comment: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: `double number = "";` causes an error. `double number = 0;` will do the (guessed) expected. And `number;` will surely cause a compiler error. not sure which result you expect here.

Answer (score 1):

I have two findings here:

```
number += rate_num;
```

I guess you want a sum of the rates. Since number is defined as a string you will get a string as result where all rates are concatenated. Define number as double:

```
double number = 0;
```

Second is the line after the while-loop:

```
number;
```

What do you want to archive here? This line will not compile neither if number is a string nor double. If this code is part of a method you pssibly want to return the calculated sum of rates. So you could

```
return number;
```

But first close your DB connection